# loop in tuple until a certain index is reach

Tags: python

I have this function that creates a WKT string formated

```
def _dump_point(obj, fmt, dim=2):
    coords = obj['coordinates']
    pt = 'POINT (%s)' % ' '.join(fmt % c for c in coords)
    return pt
```

`coords` is a tuple of float that can have 2 or 3 elements like `(0.3455 , 4.234)`or`(24.324 , 3.123 , 4.545)`

I would like to use the `dim` parameter to loop in the coords until a certain index. If `dim` is 2 I'd like to join the first 2 items of the tuple ignoring the third.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

slice using dim as the index:

```
coords[:dim]
```

For example:

```
In [8]: coords = (24.324 , 3.123 , 4.545)

In [9]: dim = 2

In [10]: coords[:dim]
Out[10]: (24.324, 3.123)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to only take `coords[:dim]`.

```
pt = 'POINT (%s)' % ' '.join(fmt % c for c in coords[:dim])
```

Answer (score 2):

Just take the number of elements defined by `dim` then, like this:

```
pt = 'POINT (%s)' % ' '.join(fmt % c for c in coords[0:dim])
```